# VSCODE Issue: "Cannot build and debug because the active file is not a C or C++ source file."

Tags: c++

I am trying to run my code but this line: "Cannot build and debug because the active file is not a C or C++ source file" pops up.

Here is my task.json

```
"tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I have am new to C++ and just installed MSYS

Comment: MSYS is a good place to start, but if you really are new to C++, can I talk you into using [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) rather than Visual Studio Code?  The community edition almost always works right out of the box, allowing you to learn C++ with fewer, "Did I screw up the code or the IDE configuration?" slow-downs. Once you're more familiar with the language, there's more room to experiment with the more difficult to use tools.

Comment: Side note: This is one of the rare places where an image, a screenshot of your IDE so we can see exactly what you see and exactly what the IDE thinks is selected, is appropriate in a Stack Overflow post.  I don't know if you have the reputation banked to make the image visible, but we can (and will when the image adds value to the post) help with that.

Comment: Active file means the one you're editing currently. Choose the file you want to compile and press F5 again.

Comment: What @LouisGo said. But note that if you continue with VSCode (and you really shouldn't) then you are going to have to edit that tasks.json file as soon as you want to compile a program with more than one source file. `"${file}",`, that's the active file, that's the only file you can compile.

Comment: Yeah, I'll suggest https://godbolt.org/ if you want to test for single source cases. For multiple source files, use cmake/make/automake instead for managing the compilation.